# Unable to build the pom file. An unknown compilation problem occurred

Tags: java, maven-3, pom.xml

I am building project using maven clean install build. Getting compilation error.
I also tried by changing the compiler version. But it didn't help.

It says Changes detected - recompiling the module!
 Compiling 492 source files to D:....\target\classes

I am stuck here.

Let me know if any details are required.

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_45). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:126)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:45)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.SymbolMetadata.setDeclarationAttributesWithCompletion(SymbolMetadata.java:161)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.setDeclarationAttributesWithCompletion(Symbol.java:215)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.actualEnterAnnotations(MemberEnter.java:952)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.access$600(MemberEnter.java:64)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$5.run(MemberEnter.java:876)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1075)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
    [INFO] 1 error
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  19.118 s`enter code here`
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-20T20:33:04 + 05:30`enter code here`
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: "*`... Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates...`*"

Comment: Your jdk seems to be outdated: `1.8.0_45`, latest seems to be `1.8.0_221`. Try updating it.

Comment: It may be a problem with your JDK. Can you provide your code ?

Comment: `1.8.0_45` is an [**old**](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_dates.xml) (October 15, 2013) build of Java; you should consider upgrading your JDK.

Comment: I have also tried with the version 1.8.0_181. But still the same

Comment: @SébastienTemprado I will not be able to provide my code due to security restrictions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly a compiler bug.

Googling for this:

```
      at com.sun.tools.javac.code.SymbolMetadata.setDeclarationAttributesWithCompletion(SymbolMetadata.java:161)
```

... gives a number of bug reports with similar stacktraces.  Unfortunately, most of them have been closed as "Unconfirmed" because the reporter didn't bother to follow up with a reproducible example.

The following one is worth looking at:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183187

These problems seem to be related to package-info files; e.g. having two such files in a directory, or by having a package-info file with an incorrect `package` declaration.  The workarounds suggested by the person who submitted the bug report are:

> - remove the duplicate package-info.java file
> - or: do not use annotations in the package-info.java files
> - or: do not use annotation processors

If this doesn't help, you should submit another bug report.  Be sure to provide sufficient information to allow the Oracle engineers to reproduce your problem ... or you are wasting their (and your) time.

Another workaround may be to switch to a later version of Java; e.g. Java 11.  (One of the bug reports said that upgrading solved the problem for them.)